# Exchange 2013 Room mailboxes, reminders set to none

Tags: exchange-2013, outlook-2010

We are currently trying to implement a room mailbox as a team calendar.

The idea is, that everyone should be able to send a meeting request to the calendar and this should be accepted automatically. If a team member has this Exchange account configured in his Outlook profile, he should get the corresponding reminders.

This is working perfectly, in theory.

Unfortunately, the room mailbox seems to automatically set the reminders of accepted meetings to "None", rendering my whole effort useless.

Is this normal behavior?
We are using an Exchange 2013 environment with Outlook 2010. I've already re-created the account multiple times and gave a few PowerShell cmdlets a shot, set DisableReminders to $false, set the DefaultReminderTime to something other than 15 minutes and so on.

Any hint on having reminders enabled on room mailboxes would be really much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Even if you got the reminders to stay on, it wouldn't work. You only get reminders for your mailbox, not additional mailboxes.

Comment: That's what I thought, but it is not true. If you add another Exchange account to your profile, not just another mailbox to your Exchange account, then you will definitively get the reminders from the second calendar. This has been introduced in Outlook 2010 or so, it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Only adding room mailbox to user mailbox account will work for reminder on calendar. Here are the test result:

1. User1 has full access permission on room1 and adds room mailbox as additional mailbox. Reminder will not work when
   [adding as additional mailbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdveN.png)

Then user3 book a meeting on Room1, on user1's mailbox, reminder is configured to none on this calendar.

2. User1 adds room mailbox as additional account. Then user3 books a meeting on room1, And user3 will receive this
   [reminder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ajsw1.png)

Comment: Hi, yes, that's right. I already figured that out ("If a team member has this Exchange account configured in his Outlook profile..."). The problem is, that the reminders are always set to "none" - I can see them pop up for half a second, if they've been created overdue.